# Abstract Class error in unity mapbox sdk

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapbox

I am following the mapbox tutorial to get a map in unity3D. Specifically i'm following this [link](https://www.mapbox.com/help/unity-mesh-pt-1/).

However, I have a problem with adding the abstract class to the map game object. The tutorial expressly says to add the abstract class to the game object, however I cant add it and when I try to drag the script I get the error "Cant add script behavior AbstractMap. The script  class can't be abstract!"

When I look at the script it is indeed abstract like "`public abstract class AbstractMap : MonoBehaviour, IMap`" and removing it causes a host of other errors and I dont feel like I should be editting the sdk. The tutorial and what I actually see seems a little off so im guessing there may be changes in the SDK not yet updated in the tutorial.

Would appreciate if someone could assist me in solving this issue.

Comment: Hi, maybe you can try with BasicMap (which inherits from AbstractMap). Also you can check the examples and see different implementations.

Comment: @mayo thanks, that worked